# Integration of CKEditor in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, integration, ckeditor

I am trying to integrate CKEditor in Netbeans to my simple web application. I did follow the documentation given in their official site, but cudnt install. It just shows a textarea instead of the editor. 
Is there any tutorial on how to integrate or can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,
Shilpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are missing to load `css & js` files. please check again & tell me if `css & js` files is downloaded & working.

[image]

Comment: That's more material for a comment

Comment: I am using js file (<script type="text/javascript" src="../ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>) and css (config.contentsCss='ckeditor/contents.css') files in my application. Still not loading.

Comment: please check the location of files in and try to set the exact path. once the css & js will load, you can see the complete editor including menu tools.

Comment: js is in WEB-INF folder under ckeditor directory and css in config.js These are the locations specified according to the documentation.

Comment: can you give the link of documentation, you are following

Comment: Hey,Changed the location of ckeditor from under WEB-INF to a new folder and it started working.. Thanks a lot...                               The link of documentation that I was following is "http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Java/Integration". In the documentation it said to put under WEB-INF folder. Anyways, Thanks again.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just have get ckeditor folder from http://ckeditor.com and put it outside the WEB-INF folder.And keep the ckeditor jar file in *WEB-INF/lib* folder.If you use jsp page get the include this tag in your page 
`<%@ taglib prefix="ckeditor" uri="http://ekeditor.com"%>` and in the body section of the html page create one textarea and replace it with `<ckeditor:replace parameters />.`

If you want to write all the toolbars and events in java and get them into jsp page use script lets and import these libraries.  `<% import page="com.ckeditor.EventHandler"%>`.
If you want more examples on java refer here http://svn.ckeditor.com/CKEditor.Java. Hope this helps.